# How to add trace to an R autoplot generated by in Tidyverse?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, time-series, tidyverse

I am pretty new to R programming and there is a question that I couldn't find the answer for. I try to visualize a time series with simple exponential prediction. As you can see in the code below, I used autoplot function to plot the results of the prediction.

```
library(tidyverse)

dfExc <- read.csv("C:/Users/olyaa/Desktop/Time Series Forecasting Gig/EURJPY Exchange/EURJPY_series.csv")


EURJPY_NPH <- dfExc$EURJPY_High

len <- length(EURJPY_NPH)
trainFac <- 0.8


thr = as.integer(trainFac*len)

EURJPY_NPH_train <- window(EURJPY_NPH,end = thr)
EURJPY_NPH_valid <- window(EURJPY_NPH,start = thr)

lenValid <- length(EURJPY_NPH_valid)
lenTrain <- length(EURJPY_NPH_train)


EURJPY_NPH_train_ses <- ses(EURJPY_NPH_train,
                alpha = .2,
                h = lenValid)

plot1 <- autoplot(EURJPY_NPH_train_ses)
plot1
```

The code above produced the plot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUbEK.png)

I want to add a custom time series onto this plot but I am not sure how to do that. The 'EURJPY_NPH_train_ses' object is a list of different data-types and I am not sure how can I manipulate it so it can also display the time series I want in addition to the prediction.

Thanks in advance...

I tried to search of a way to modify 'EURJPY_NPH_train_ses' so it also includes my custom time series in addition to the simple exponential model prediction to no avail.